# SSIS Derived Column vs SQL Update Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am trying to determine which is faster in a SSIS package. I have multiple (100's) csv files that have about 150 columns of scientific precision data (38,20) for different types of scenarios. The table is layed out the same way with some other columns. The data sometimes comes in with whitespace/empty data and I have to change this to null for a data conversion at a later time.

I am trying to determine if I should go with derived columns (150) to turn the data into nulls or use a massive sql update statement for updating each column.

Thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: There's no definitive answer we can give here, as we don't have enough information. For example, we have no idea how many rows you'll also be looking at updating. Easiest way to find out which is fastest is to test. I wouldn't like to guess, however, I would imagine that updating 100's of tables, with 150 columns is not going to be a cheap task; regardless of how many rows are in each table.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, any time you have a choice of doing a transformation in either the SSIS dataflow, or in TSQL, the TSQL way is usually faster.

However, that's only generally speaking, and the only way to know if it holds true in any specific case is to test it.